# Sliding Frame effect in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, effect

Is there already workable example of a swing component which allows adding boxes/panels and then animate them to produce a sliding frame effect?

What I am looking for is a simple component. It should have something like circle buttons at the bottom which when clicked will slide the view to the right place.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Animated Transitions](http://today.java.net/pub/a//today/2007/10/23/create-moving-experiences-with-animated-transitions.html). It is a library explained in Chet Haase & Romain Guy's [Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/) book. BSD licensed sources are available [here](http://java.net/projects/filthyrichclients/sources/svn/show).

Comment: this is all nice but I find it really hard to get any of the examples running... it seems that these libraries are largely outdated

Answer (score 2):

May be this could help as well
http://java-sl.com/tip_slider.html